# Double Minor Penalty Kill Counts as 1 or 2 Kills?

Tags: ice-hockey, statistics, nhl

In NHL hockey when you receive a double minor penalty (4:00 penalty given for example high sticking leading to bleeding) does this count as 2 separate penalty kills if no goals are scored during the 4 minutes or does it only count as 1 penalty kill? And for that matter if a goal is scored in the first 2 minutes but not in the 2nd 2 minute penalty, is it considered one failure and one kill?

I am just curious how this is kept statistically. But my guess would be that it counts as 2 penalty kills.

Comment: And how does it work if there is a power play goal scored during the first 2:00 does the second penalty start right away?

Comment: If a goal is scored during the first 2 min then that will negate the first powerplay. The second minor will start counting after the puck drop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A double minor counts as two separate penalties, one after the other. When keeping the game statistics, therefore, you count them separately as well.

This leads to the situation where a four-minute double minor counts as two power-plays but a five minute major penalty counts as just a single power-play.

Comment: Can you add a reference for this?

Comment: I can't point to a specific rule, but I found an example from a recent game which shows how a double-minor is counted for statistical purposes: [New York - Washington](http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm?id=2011030216). NYR are 0/5 for power-plays. Washington received four penalties, one of which was a double minor to Halpern at 12:05 of the second period.

Comment: Does it count twice even if the match ends before the second one starts?

Comment: Powerplays are counted as they occur not when the penalty is given. For example, in team A gets a double minor and team B gets a major part-way through the first of the double minors, the second of the double minor power plays will never occur. The result would be one power play to each team. Likewise, if the game ends before a power play starts, then it won't be counted for statistical purposes.

Comment: I think if you get a double minor at say 19:00 of the last period (assuming no OT and no goals are scored during the first minor), the 2 min 2nd minor penalty still count and is added to the stats